# How to allow remote mysql login ?

Tags: php, mysql, vagrant

I have simple vagrant multi-machine config:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-16.04"
  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "vagrant/ubuntu-16.04/provision.sh"
  config.vm.synced_folder "ed", "/var/www/html"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 1024
    v.cpus = 2
  end
  config.vm.define "node1", primary: true do |node|
    node.vm.hostname = 'node1'
    node.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.56.101"
    node.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 10122, id: "ssh"
    node.vm.provision :hosts, :sync_hosts => true
  end
  config.vm.define "node2" do |node|
    node.vm.hostname = "node2"
    node.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.56.102"
    node.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 22, host: 10123, id: "ssh"
    node.vm.provision :hosts, :sync_hosts => true
  end
end
```

On `node1` I have php and on `node2` I have mysql.

When I run `mysql -uuser -ppass -P3306 -hlocalhost` from `vagrant@node2` it works,

but when I try run `mysql -uuser -ppass -P3306 -h192.168.56.102` from `vagrant@node1` it won't work, I get error:

> ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.56.102' (111)

I can ping node1 from node2 and vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In mysql, remote user login is disabled by default. It only allow localhost for security reason.**

For cross verification, login to mysql and run command:

```
mysql> select user,host from mysql.user;
+------+--------------------------------+
| user | host                           |
+------+--------------------------------+
| root | localhost                      | 
| root | ::1                            |
+------+--------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If it is giving `localhost` only. it means you are only allowed to login from `localhost` and user as `root`(in this example).

If you want to allow login from remote system then you have to add like:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

This command will allow login from all remote IP and give access to all database to username `user`.

If you want to allow from specific IP address and allow access only specific database then you can run like:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasename.* TO 'user'@'ipaddress' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

**Note:** Don't forget to change `bind-address` in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

Open file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and change `bind-address` from `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0` or comment out `bind-address` and restart `mysql` service.

Comment: @Vladimir, let me know if you face any problem. :)

Answer (score 2):

This can happen if the MySQL port (default is `3306`) is blocked by a firewall.

The other possible reason is the `bind_address` setting in the MySQL configuration file. This is set to `127.0.0.1` by default. Set it to `0.0.0.0` to enable MySQL for all IP addresses.